# Incremental/decreasing variable name in WHILE loop (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to decrease a variable name number in WHILE loop, so it starts as @chk3, then @chk2, and so on.

This is the code I currently have, but the "variable" I create on `@chk_current` is treated as text.

How can I create an actual variable that is decreased using fix text `@chk` and then @task_total number? So on the first loop variable name would be `@chk3` (value = NO), second `@chk2` (value = YES), then `@chk1` (value = YES) and then the code will exit the loop.

```
DECLARE ALL...

SET @chk1 = 'YES'
SET @chk2 = 'YES'
SET @chk3 = 'NO'

SELECT @task_total = COUNT(*) 
FROM R5TASKCHECKLISTS 
WHERE TCH_TASK = @tasknum

WHILE @task_total >= 0
BEGIN
    SET @chk_current = CONCAT('@chk', @task_total)

    INSERT INTO R5TRACKINGDATA
        (TKD_TRANS, TKD_TRACKDATE,
         TKD_PROMPTDATA1, TKD_PROMPTDATA2, TKD_PROMPTDATA3,
         TKD_PROMPTDATA4, TKD_PROMPTDATA5, TKD_PROMPTDATA6,
         TKD_PROMPTDATA7, TKD_PROMPTDATA8, TKD_PROMPTDATA9,
         TKD_PROMPTDATA10, TKD_PROMPTDATA11, TKD_PROMPTDATA12,
         TKD_PROMPTDATA13, TKD_PROMPTDATA14, TKD_PROMPTDATA15) 
    VALUES ('AO01',   --TKD_TRANS
            GETDATE(),
            @next_evtcode,    -- EVT_CODE
            @ot_desc,         -- EVT_DESC
            @ot_dates,        -- EVT_DATE (dd/mm/yyyy)
            '100',            -- EVT_MRC
            '282',            -- EVT_ORG
            'PMM',            -- EVT_JOBTYPE
            @ot_dates,        -- EVT_REPORTED (dd/mm/yyyy)
            @ot_object,       -- EVT_OBJECT
            '282',            -- EVT_OBJECT_ORG
            @ot_dates,        -- EVT_TARGET (dd/mm/yyyy)
            @ot_dates,        -- EVT_COMPLETED (dd/mm/yyyy)
            @ot_createdby,    -- EVT_ENTEREDBY
            @tasklist,        -- TSK_CODE
            @task_total,      -- ACK_SEQUENCE
            @chk_current      -- ACK_NO_YES (NO or YES)
        )

    SET @task_total = @task_total - 1;
END
```

Comment: This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) if I am honest; what are you *actually* trying to do here? A `WHILE` loop is one of the slowest things you can do in T-SQL.

Comment: Also I'm not sure why you would think that `@chk_current` would be infered as "refer to the variable of the same name as the value as `@chk_current`", as that would *imply* that you expect `@chk1` to mean "refer to the variable of the same name as the value of `@chk1`"; you'd just always end up with an error when a variable has a value of a variable name that hasn't been declared. When referenced a variable provides it's value *only., If that variable has the value `'chk1'` then referencing that variable with return the value `'chk1'`.

Comment: @Larnu Just do the insers X number of times (in the example case, 3 times) changing the last variable name to be chk + task_total (chk3, chk2, etc...) so it gets the values from variables declared before the while loop (YES, YES, NO)

Comment: Why use a `WHILE` loop at all? Why not just `INSERT` all 3 rows in 1 `INSERT` statement?

Comment: Because the value of @task_total will change. So sometimes it will loop 3 times, but others maybe 4 or 5.
In the code I just put 3 chk variables as an example, but it can have more

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Why use a `WHILE` when you can insert *many* rows in a single `INSERT`?

Comment: How can I do it in a single insert, when the amount of rows is unknown? Because othe value of ``@task_total`` will be diferent depending on ``@tasknum``

Comment: Where are these values coming from? An application? Use a table Type parameter. Like I said before, this is most certainly an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/); we need to know the *real* problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: Values from all chk (up to 10) come from PHP post, and then inserted into an array
``   $vars = array($task_code,$activo,$user,$chk1,$chk2,$chk3,$chk4,$chk5,$chk6,$chk7,$chk8,$chk9,$chk10);    ``
The final idea is to have in the query $vars[X] depending on the chk number.

Comment: This is the perfect time to use a table valued parameter. It can handle any number of rows and allows for your insert to be a single statement.

Comment: I would make the point that your table has some design challenges. Column names with numbers like that are a nightmare to work with. Why not name the columns with an actual name?

Answer (score 1):

Boiling your code down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

```
DECLARE @chk1 varchar(5) = 'YES'
      , @chk2 varchar(5) = 'YES'
      , @chk3 varchar(5) = 'NO'
      , @task_total int = 3

--SELECT @task_total = COUNT(*) FROM R5TASKCHECKLISTS WHERE TCH_TASK = '123' --VALUE IS 3

WHILE @task_total >= 0
BEGIN

        SET @chk_current = CONCAT('@chk', @task_total)

        INSERT INTO R5TRACKINGDATA
        (
            TKD_PROMPTDATA14,
            TKD_PROMPTDATA15
            ) VALUES (
             @task_total --ACK_SEQUENCE
            ,@chk_current --ACK_NO_YES (NO or YES)
        )

        SET @task_total = @task_total - 1;

END
```

SQL doesn't use arrays.  It uses tables.  So, to do this in a loop:

```
DECLARE @chk table (id int identity(1,1), val varchar(5))
insert @chk (val)
      select 'YES'
union select 'YES'
union select 'NO'
union select 'NO'
union select 'YES'
union select 'NO'

declare @chk_current varchar(5)
declare @task_total int = 3
--SELECT @task_total = COUNT(*) FROM R5TASKCHECKLISTS WHERE TCH_TASK = '123' --VALUE IS 3

WHILE @task_total >= 0
BEGIN

        SELECT @chk_current = c.val
        FROM @chk c
        WHERE c.id = @task_total

        INSERT INTO R5TRACKINGDATA
        (
            TKD_PROMPTDATA14,
            TKD_PROMPTDATA15
            ) VALUES (
             @task_total --ACK_SEQUENCE
            ,@chk_current --ACK_NO_YES (NO or YES)
        )

        SET @task_total = @task_total - 1;
END
```

If the number of variables (@chk*) is unknown, I'll assume you're getting them from the data.  This simulates that and uses a single `INSERT` statement.

```
with 
chk (id, val) as (
        select 1, 'YES'
  union select 2, 'YES'
  union select 3, 'NO'
  union select 4, 'NO'
  union select 5, 'YES'
  union select 6, 'NO'
)

insert into R5TRACKINGDATA (TKD_PROMPTDATA14, TKD_PROMPTDATA15)
select c.id, c.val
from chk c
where c.id <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM R5TASKCHECKLISTS WHERE TCH_TASK = '123')
```

So, not accounting for likely SQL injection possibilities, your php code may look like:

```
$sql = "with 
chk (id, val) as (
        select 1, " . $chk1 . "
  union select 2, " . $chk2 . "
  union select 3, " . $chk3 . "
  union select 4, " . $chk4 . "
  union select 5, " . $chk5 . "
  union select 6, " . $chk6 . "
  union select 7, " . $chk7 . "
  union select 8, " . $chk8 . "
  union select 9, " . $chk9 . "
  union select 10, " . $chk10 . "
)

insert into R5TRACKINGDATA (TKD_PROMPTDATA14, TKD_PROMPTDATA15)
select c.id, c.val
from chk c
where c.id <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM R5TASKCHECKLISTS WHERE TCH_TASK = '123')";
```

Comment: While this would work I just can't condone using a while loop for a bunch of inserts.

Comment: I totally agree.  Did you see the final solution at the bottom of my answer?